# How to apply a newly-created Domain to an existing Column?

Tags: postgresql, alter-table, domain

In Postgres 9.4 Beta 1, I successfully created a domain of type `VARCHAR`, `fuel_domain_`. The domain checks that a value is any of 5 possible strings, `coal`, `gas`, `wind`, `hydro`, `other`.

```sql
CREATE DOMAIN fuel_domain_
  AS character varying
  COLLATE pg_catalog."default"
  NOT NULL
  CONSTRAINT fuel_check_ CHECK (VALUE::text = ANY (ARRAY['coal'::character varying, 'gas'::character varying, 'hydro'::character varying, 'wind'::character varying, 'other'::character varying]::text[]));
ALTER DOMAIN fuel_domain_
  OWNER TO postgres_admin_;
```

> ➤ How do I apply this new domain to an existing column?

The [doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createdomain.html) seems to say that a domain should be specified in place of the usual data type when declaring a column.

So I tried and failed to re-define the column’s data type from `VARCHAR` to the new domain. The base data type of the domain is the same, so the data types should not be in conflict. This SQL for a table `unit_` and column `fuel_` fails with a syntax error at or near "COLUMN":

```sql
ALTER COLUMN unit_.fuel_ SET DATA TYPE fuel_domain_;
```

**WORKAROUND**
As a workaround, I was able to delete the column and successfully recreate it with this SQL:

```
ALTER TABLE unit_ ADD COLUMN fuel_ fuel_domain_;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Incorrect SQL was the problem. The `ALTER COLUMN` must be part of an `ALTER TABLE`.

This SQL does indeed alter the data type of the existing column from `VARCHAR` to the newly-created domain.

```
ALTER TABLE unit_
ALTER COLUMN fuel_ 
SET DATA TYPE fuel_domain_;
```